# Auctex previews, change foreground color of text

Tags: latex, customize, preview-latex

I am using a dark theme and the latex previews from auctex are created with black text color. How can I change it?
What I can do is change the background color to white (in Preview Reference Face customization), then I can at least read the text but it is irritating.
Setting the foreground there did not work for me.

I also already tried to inject \color{white} into the latex commands somehow but without luck. Where would be the right place?

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the `preview-pdf-color-adjust-method` option.

Apparently it should use automatically the same foreground color as the buffer text, but at least in my case the problem was that I have only Ghostscript 9.26 installed. As a workaround I downloaded [the latest Ghostscript binary](https://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html) and modified `preview-gs-command` to point to it.